# Is there any way to execute .cmd file in Unix?

Tags: shell, cmd

How to create a .cmd file in .cmd file and pass variable in it to execute some command.

`Is there any way to execute .cmd file in Unix ?`

Kindly advice

Thanks,

Comment: Question unclear. No previous attempt demonstrated.

Comment: What's a `.cmd` file?

Comment: Question seems pretty clear to me. You could argue it's better suited for superuser.com, but it's a valid question.

Comment: That depends on what the script does. You'll have to post it to really tell.

Comment: I have cmd files in a Solaris server and I was able to run it by calling it directly from the terminal, e.g. `/folder/folder/script.cmd <enter>`

Answer (score 2):

**No, not really**

The `.cmd` files in windows are interpreted by the windows `cmd.exe` program. If you open one up, you'll find a `.cmd` file contains text commands to be executed.

In the Unix world the equivalent to command files are shell scripts. These have a `.sh` extension and are usually interpreted by the `bash` program.

Read more about shell scripts [online](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)

**Well maybe...**

you can run the `cmd.exe` program on Linux, Solaris Mac and BSD by using a compatibility layer called [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) However, because of differences between the platforms, you will have to revise you scripts and manually check that things like paths and executable names are still valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to run 1st .cmd file in windows and pass information like Device Name and IP address to second .cmd file which will be run from Linux.

Comment: @RohitEmc I'm not sure what you mean.